# Enable resuming interrupt download in REST web service using Java

Tags: java, http, rest

I am writing a REST web service for clients to download large data files. As part of this, I would like to implement a feature to enable resuming interrupt downloads in case an exception occurs or the connection is lost on the original request.

I did some research online and found that supporting Range/If-Range properties in the request header might be the solution, as indicated in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.

My question are

1. In the scope of REST web service, is it the most commonly used and best practice to support Range/If-Range properties in the client HTTP request header, or just pass the byte offset as a query parameter in the client GET request, e.g., **hostname:port/download?token=?byteoffset=?**?
2. If taking the former approach, on the server side, is there a standard way to handle request with Range field in JAX-RS specification (I am using Java)? The straightforward way is to just open an InputStream from the file and bypass the given # of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, don't use parameters that have to do with *meta*-information on the resource (or the part of it you need), so you should be using the Range, and keep sure the server allows that.

Note that, for example, `byteoffset` is not a meaningful part, component or semantically interesting bit of the resource itself, but a way of overcoming partial content (also, identical for all the resources, so you have to use the headers allowed for that, and hey! they're there for that).