# Does REST Web Service Support Range Header for serving zip file?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, download

I am developing a Rest Full Web Service in Java Using Spring/Apache CXF, this service will be responsible to serve a zipped file to the web service client.

The web service client will also be written in java , It is part of a JavaFX Desktop Application.

The size of this file can be 20MB. I want to enable resume download support. So that if a client downloading is interrupted. It can resume download from the point it was broken.

Are Range Headers support in Rest Service? Any pointers ?

Found relevant Question, but no final response to query.

[Enable resuming interrupt download in REST web service using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284946/enable-resuming-interrupt-download-in-rest-web-service-using-java)

Thanks 
Mukesh Katariya

Comment: REST is just "the web" done properly. You should read up more about REST before developing your service.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely - you are free to specify any range units you like.

From RFC 2616:

> 3.12 Range Units
>
> HTTP/1.1 allows a client to request
>   that only part (a range of) the
>   response entity be included within the
>   response. HTTP/1.1 uses range    units
>   in the Range (section 14.35) and
>   Content-Range (section 14.16)
>   header fields. An entity can be broken
>   down into subranges according    to
>   various structural units.
>
> ```
>   range-unit       = bytes-unit | other-range-unit
>   bytes-unit       = "bytes"
>   other-range-unit = token
> ```
>
> The only range unit defined by
>   HTTP/1.1 is "bytes". HTTP/1.1
>   implementations MAY ignore ranges
>   specified using other units.